# how to bind rows into one row but still keep original rows

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like the on the left. I would like to put all rows inputs into one row,and still keep old rows. How should I do this?

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(c1 = c("Student Enrollment", "750"), c2 = c("Faculty Number", 
"21"), c3 = c("Graduated", "65")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = rbind(df, lapply(df, paste, collapse = "\n"))
output
#                        c1                 c2            c3
# 1      Student Enrollment     Faculty Number     Graduated
# 2                     750                 21            65
# 3 Student Enrollment\n750 Faculty Number\n21 Graduated\n65
```

In the console, line breaks print as `\n`. If you `View()` it they will print as spaces. There are probably some nice table formatting packages that actually display linebreaks within a cell.

You could, of course, replace `"\n"` in my code with `" "` to use a space instead of a linebreak.

Comment: `rbind(df, sapply(df, paste, collapse = " "))` might also be a good fit depending on OP's needs

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is below. In case we need to have the concatenated number in a different line, we can use `collapse = "\n"` instead:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df, map_dfr(df, ~ str_c(.x, collapse = " ")))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   c1                     c2                c3          
#>   <chr>                  <chr>             <chr>       
#> 1 Student Enrollment     Faculty Number    Graduated   
#> 2 750                    21                65          
#> 3 Student Enrollment 750 Faculty Number 21 Graduated 65
```

Comment: Lib edit helped clarify, but where does the `str_c` come from?

Comment: In the input, the columns are already `character` class. They couldn't be numeric with strings like "Student Enrollment" in the first row. The column names are "c1", "c2", "c3".

Comment: Thanks for having commented my answer, @GregorThomas! You are absolutely right! My mistake is due to using the dataframe of a previous question from the same OP.

Comment: @Chris: `str_c` is the `tidyverse` version of base R `paste`: [Join multiple strings into a single string](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_c.html).

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution similar to @GregorThomas':

```r
rbind(df, do.call(paste, c(asplit(df, 1), sep = "\n")))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  c1                        c2                   c3             
  <chr>                     <chr>                <chr>          
1 "Student Enrollment"      "Faculty Number"     "Graduated"    
2 "750"                     "21"                 "65"           
3 "Student Enrollment\n750" "Faculty Number\n21" "Graduated\n65"
```

If you write the data out to an excel file (e.g. `openxlsx::write.xlsx`), `\n` will be presented as linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `summarise` with `across`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ c(.x, str_c(.x, collapse = " "))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  c1                     c2                c3          
  <chr>                  <chr>             <chr>       
1 Student Enrollment     Faculty Number    Graduated   
2 750                    21                65          
3 Student Enrollment 750 Faculty Number 21 Graduated 65
```